# only generate a part of pandas profiling report

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I would like to use pandas profiling to generate some kind of summary to look at on a regular basis. I don't need the whole report though, I'm just interested in the `alerts` or `warnings` section. So I was wondering if there is a way to only output this? If there was a way that would not even create the rest of the report that would be amazing. Unfortunately I cannot find much about that.

```
import pandas_profiling as pp
profile = pp.ProfileReport(data, title = "data")
```

Comment: Not sure if there is. You can do a lot with configuration though: https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/advanced_usage.html

Comment: hmm, i don't even find the three main sections "overview", "alerts" and "reproduction". Do you know if the documentation says anything about them, I can't see anything which seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `minimal=True`. It uses a minimal configuration file where the most expensive computations are turned off by default.

```
import ydata_profiling as pp
profile = pp.ProfileReport(data, title = "data", minimal=True)
```

Reference: https://ydata-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/getting_started/quickstart.html